# How to sort by a specific value with localeCompare?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to sort my current array by having **live** at the front, instead of sorting it alphabetically so that the items with `live` will be at the front, followed by `schedule` and lastly `end`, but the way I'm doing it now with `localeCompare`, it will only sort alphabetically.

So how can I do so to sort the array in a specific way that I want?

**Array Before Sorting Example**

```
const [bulletins] = useState([
     {
       id: 1,
       liveStatus: 'live',
     },
     {
       id: 2,
       liveStatus: 'live',
     },
     {
       id: 3,
       liveStatus: 'end',
     },
     {
       id: 4,
       liveStatus: 'schedule',
     },
     {
       id: 5,
       liveStatus: 'end',
     }
]);
```

**Sorted Array Example**

```
const [bulletins] = useState([
     {
       id: 3,
       liveStatus: 'end',
     },
     {
       id: 5,
       liveStatus: 'end',
     },
     {
       id: 2,
       liveStatus: 'live',
     },
     {
       id: 1,
       liveStatus: 'live',
     },
     {
       id: 4,
       liveStatus: 'schedule',
     }
]);
```

```
const displayBulletins = bulletins
    .sort((a,b) => {
        return a.liveStatus.localeCompare(b.liveStatus)
    })
    .map((bulletin) => {
        return (
            <Fragment key={bulletin.id}>
                <BulletinList
                    bulletin={bulletin}
                />
            </Fragment>
        );
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `indexOf` to check the first letter in a list of sorted letters ('lse' in this case):

```js
const bulletins = [{id: 1,liveStatus: 'live',},{id: 2,liveStatus: 'live',},{id: 3,liveStatus: 'end',},{id: 4,liveStatus: 'schedule',},{id: 5,liveStatus: 'end',}];

bulletins.sort((a, b) => 'lse'.indexOf(a.liveStatus[0]) - 'lse'.indexOf(b.liveStatus[0]));

console.log(bulletins);
```

Answer (score 1):

Then no need to sort the elements, all you can use is [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and arrange in the way you like

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    liveStatus: "live",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    liveStatus: "live",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    liveStatus: "end",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    liveStatus: "schedule",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    liveStatus: "end",
  },
];

const dict = { live: 0, schedule: 1, end: 2 };
const resultObj = Array.from({ length: Object.keys(dict).length + 1 }, () => []);


const result = arr
  .reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[dict[curr.liveStatus] ?? resultObj.length - 1].push(curr);
    return acc;
  }, resultObj)
  .flat();

console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```